# Capture constexpr-ness in function arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

For various reasons I am looking for a way to capture the constexpr-ness of arguments passed to a function. It's a bit tricky to explain so I think code best demonstrates what I like to achieve

```
#include <vector> // For std::size_t
#include <cstdio>

namespace
{
  template<std::size_t N, typename ...TArgs>
  constexpr int cstrlen (char const (&s) [N], std::size_t i = 0) noexcept
  {
    return i < N && s[i] != 0
      ? 1 + cstrlen (s, i + 1)
      : 0
      ;
  }

  template<std::size_t N, typename ...TArgs>
  inline void silly_printf (char const (&format) [N], TArgs && ...args) noexcept
  {
    static_assert (cstrlen (format) > 0, "format must not be empty string");
    printf (format, std::forward<TArgs> (args)...);
  }

}

#define SILLY_PRINTF(format, ...)                                           \
  static_assert (cstrlen (format) > 0, "format must not be empty string");  \
  printf (format, ##__VA_ARGS__);

int main()
{
  // This works but relies on macros
  SILLY_PRINTF ("Hello: %d", 1);

  // This doesn't work
  silly_printf ("Hello: %d", 1);
  return 0;
}
```

I can't get `silly_printf` to work as I want it to. The compiler complains that the expression doesn't evaluate to a constant. We know it's constexpr when calling `silly_print` with a string literal but the constexpr-ness gets lost (I am using VS2015 here by the way).

I was thinking perhaps I can add constexpr to parameters (much like const) but no success there.

I can work-around this using macros (demonstrated by `SILLY_PRINTF` macro) but that feels like a failure.

Any ideas most welcome.

PS. What I am really is trying to achieve is slightly less silly

Comment: Replace `cstrlen(format)` with `N`?

Comment: A way is to use a `template <char...Cs> struct char_list{};`. but the way to build it from literal string that I know use macro too(so it results to something like `silly_printf(TO_CHAR_LIST("hello: %d"), 1)`).

Comment: @KerrekSB: That doesn't handle `"\0Hidden text"`.

Comment: The macro `SILLY_PRINTF ("Hello: %d", 1);` does not work either. I used your code and commented out the line `silly_printf ("Hello: %d", 1);` in main, and got the error on `SILLY_PRINTF`macro. The reason is that despite the `constexpr` specifier, `ctrlen` does **not** return a constant expression, because `i` parameter is not a constant expression.

Comment: @SergeBallesta when I run with clang (3.6.0) and gcc (4.9.2) with option --std=c++14 they are able to compile the macro version. I don't know the standard well enough to say what it's supposed to do. Perhaps the compilers are too lenient?

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, it's an interesting idea but I would like to make silly_printf not require users any typing overhead over printf.

Comment: @KerrekSB this is just an example. The real source code parses the format specifier of printf in order to compile-time verification of the format string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a GNU extension (supported by g++ and clang) that allows user defined literals of the form:

```
template<typename CharT, CharT... Chars>
constexpr void operator"" _something() { }
```

With this, one can build a constexpr-string type without macros that could be used like this:

```
constexpr auto str = "testing\0length"_string;
static_assert(str.strlen() == 7, "!");
```

By encoding all the string's properties into the type, you can then static_assert on it anywhere, constexpr or not.
For example, in your silly_printf:

```
template<typename CharT, CharT... Chars, typename... Args>
void silly_printf(const constexpr_string<CharT, Chars...>& format_string, Args&&... args) {
    static_assert(format_string.strlen() > 0, "format string must not be empty");
    printf(format_string.c_str(), args...);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
silly_printf("testing %d %s %x embedded\0null"_string, 1, "2", nullptr);
```

You could also use another `operator"" _silly_printf()` returning a function object to get a syntax like `"format string"_silly_printf(args...)`.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2a37dc744bb5b1b)

Comment: Hi. I assume this relies on User-Defined Literals. It's an interesting idea as I could then do: `"My format string: %s"_format` which returns a `formatter_string` (or something like that) that is parsed and checked in compile-time. I will investigate.

Comment: @FuleSnabel unfortunately, neither relaxed constexpr nor these string user-defined literals are supported in VS2015.

Comment: relaxed  constexpr is missing but there's at least some support for UDT. This seems like something that could work for me: `constexpr std::size_t operator"" _format ( const char * deg, std::size_t n) { return n; }`

Comment: This seems the best approach to avoid my macro in C++14.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a char array reference as the argument. Here is one that I use but you need to have c++14 relaxed constexpr rules:

```
using size_t=decltype(sizeof(int));

namespace util
{
    template<typename char_t>
    constexpr size_t str_size(const char_t*)noexcept;
}

template
<typename char_t>
constexpr auto
util::
str_size
(const char_t* const a_str)noexcept->size_t
{
    const char_t* a_char=a_str;

    while(*a_char!=char_t(0))
    {
        ++a_char;
    }

    return size_t(a_char-a_str);
}

static_assert(util::str_size("hello")==size_t(5),"");
```

If you can't use c++14 a recursive version will work too. You still just use a char pointer as the argument rather than a char array reference.

Comment: Hi I will evaluate this. The relaxed rules seems like a significant improvement if I can get it to work. Is the relaxed rules standardized or something certain compiler support? Which compilers support the relaxed rules.

Comment: I guess this is what you are talking about: [N3652](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html). That would be a huge help especially to reduce template compilation depth when parsing strings. clang seems to be there but not GCC yet (version 5)

Comment: But I wonder if it stills enables me to do away with the macro. The expression still needs to be constexpr. I will need to evalute.